# CollectionView show items paging circularly

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a CollectionView with have 2 items.

`CollectionView` has `pagingEnabled`, I want to show them circularly like:

> [1] 2 -> [2] 1 -> [1] 2 -> [2] 1

Is it possible to do this with `CollectionView`

My code:

```
extension HomeViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    func configureHeaderView() {

        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)

        headerView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: headerHeight), collectionViewLayout: layout)
        headerView?.backgroundColor = .blue
        headerView?.isPagingEnabled = true
        headerView?.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

        headerView?.rx.setDelegate(self).addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
        let nib = UINib(nibName: BannerCollectionViewCell.reuseIdentifier, bundle: nil)
        headerView?.register(nib, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: BannerCollectionViewCell.reuseIdentifier)
        headerView?.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false

        tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView

        if let headerView = headerView {
            self.bannerItems.asObservable().bindTo(headerView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: BannerCollectionViewCell.reuseIdentifier, cellType: BannerCollectionViewCell.self)) {
                row, banner, cell in
                cell.banner = banner
                }.addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
        }
    }

    // MARK: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: headerHeight)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 0
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 0
    }
}
```

Comment: hi, check this library https://github.com/masoapps/infinite-uicollectionview

Answer (score 0):

Make use of UICollectionView's **scrollToItemAtIndexPath** method to move collectionView back to the first item if it reached the end and the user swiped right. Move the collectionView back to the last item if user swiped left from first item. You should set the **animation** property to **false**

```
func scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

        // Calculate where the collection view should be at the right-hand end item
        let offsetRight = collectionView.frame.size.width * CGFloat(yourDataArray.count)

        if scrollView.contentOffset.x == offsetRight {

            // user is scrolling to the right from the last item to the 'fake' item 1.
            // reposition offset to show the 'real' item 1 at the left-hand end of the collection view

            let newIndexPath = IndexPath(row: 1, section: 0)

            collectionView.scrollToItem(at: newIndexPath, at: .left, animated: false)

        } else if scrollView.contentOffset.x == 0 {

            // user is scrolling to the left from the first item to the fake 'item N'.
            // reposition offset to show the 'real' item N at the right end of the collection view

            let newIndexPath = IndexPath(row: (yourDataArray.count-2), section: 0)

            collectionView.scrollToItem(at: newIndexPath, at: .left, animated: false)
        }
    }
```